# A tree structure in SQL Server that needs to be flattened in a very special way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, tree, common-table-expression

We have a table which looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE Hierarchy (EmployeeID int not null, parentID int, orderlimit int)
CREATE TABLE Order (EmployeeID int not null, OrderSize int)
```

It's supposed to tell you the approval range for each employee on orders, and we decided to keep the employee manager's ID, in the same record, because in case an order exceeds a person's limit, his/her manager (referred to by `parentID`) should approve it.

If it exceeds the upper level again, the order should go to the higher level and so on and on, until it reaches the level where it qualifies to approve the order. If `parentID` is null for one person, this means he is the highest level in management structure AND we don't know how many possible levels we might have, and if the highest level'

To clarify consider this

```
INSERT INTO Hierarchy values 
(1,10,0),
(2,11,0),
(3,12,0),
(10,20,100),
(11,21,300),
(12,22,200),
(20,30,1000),
(21,31,2000),
(22,31,3000),
(30,40,10000),
(31,40,15000),
(40,NULL,NULL)
```

We want to create a view which returns something like this:

```
EmployeeID       ApprovalGoesTo     LowerLimit    UpperLimit
------------------------------------------------------------
1                10                  0             99
1                20                  100           999
1                30                  1000          9999
1                40                  10000         NULL
2                11                  0             299
2                21                  300           1999
2                31                  2000          14999
2                40                  15000         NULL
.
.
.
10               10                  0             100
10               20                  101           1000
10               30                  1001          10000
.
.
.
31               31                  0             15000
31               40                  15001         NULL
40               40                  0             NULL
```

So, an order with  `ORDER VALUES (1, 8999)` should go to `employeeID : 30`.

ALL values are positive, and the query shouldn't be bound to the levels of the hierarchy.

We don't want to use cursors, it means, we want to strictly use set-based operations because performance is very important in this case.

1. Can this be done with CTEs? Or simply joins? Sub queries? Nested queries?
2. Any suggestions to improve the design?

Please keep in mind that we need an answer  *independent*  of the levels of the hierarchy.

Comment: This should be tagged with recursion.

Comment: At a quick glance, it might be more trouble than it's worth to explicitly have the view show `LowerLimit`, and you don't need it - when you query the view, `UpperLimit` will be enough to get the row you want.

Comment: @AakashM I think the lower limit is helpful when doing quick queries because they can do `Where OrderSize Between LowerLimit and UpperLimit`. Without the LowerLimit they'd have to write something like a CTE with a Row_Number and join it up in some way to get the range (which is probably part of the solution here), but if they're going to do it regularly enough I think it makes sense to have in a view.

Comment: Second glance: I think I see what you're after, but your data is slightly at odds with your text. You say of your table that "It's supposed to tell you the approval limit of each employee on orders", but your data puts the *lower* limit here. So to know eg emp `1`'s *upper* limit you have to look at their *manager's* *lower* limit, which seems a bit odd. Is it supposed to be the other way round?

Comment: and lastly (for now), it seems to me that if you just want to be able to answer questions like **"What to do with `Emp 1` and `8999`?"**, you don't need a whole view, you just need a (parameterised) query, which would be easier. Is this right, or do you definitely need the whole view available?

Comment: Your sample output is incorrect. 2 goes to 11 goes to 21 goes to 30 (not 31).

Comment: @Aakash, exactly. LowerLimit and upperLimit will just makes it easier for future lookups, which are expected to be frequent.

Comment: @Aakash, I got your point about the parametric query. We'll think about it and I'll get back to you if anything changed in our design.

Comment: @user1155391 I updated my answer per your feedback and it provides the desired results that was originally specified. In your new output your mixing the conceptual LowerLimit. In your original answers the UpperLimit was 1 less than the the order Limit and the actual orderLimit value should go to the next approver. In your lower examples you have it such that the person can approve up to their order limit and next approver picks up above that. I think the second way makes more sense, but just let me know which way you want it and I'll make sure my answer aligns with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive CTE answer...

```
Create  View OrderApprovalHierachy
As
With    cte As
(
        Select  h1.employeeID, 
                h1.parentID, 
                h2.parentID As parentsparent, 
                h2.orderlimit
        From   (Select  *
                From    hierarchy n1
                Union
                Select  employeeID, 
                        employeeID as parentID, 
                        orderlimit
                From    hierarchy n2) h1
        Left    Join hierarchy h2
                On  h1.parentID = h2.EmployeeID
        Union   All
        Select  h1.employeeID, 
                h1.parentsparent, 
                h2.parentID As parentsparent, 
                h2.orderlimit
        From    cte h1
        Join    hierarchy h2
                On  h1.parentsparent = h2.EmployeeID
        Where   h1.employeeID <> h1.parentID
),      prep As
(
        Select  Row_Number() Over (Partition By EmployeeID Order By IsNull(orderLimit,2147483647) Asc) As pID, 
                EmployeeID, 
                parentID As ApprovalGoesTo, 
                orderLimit - 1 As UpperLimit, 
                orderLimit As NextLowerLimit
        From    cte
)
Select  p1.employeeID,
        p1.ApprovalGoesTo, 
        IsNull(p2.NextLowerLimit,0) As LowerLimit,
        p1.UpperLimit
From    prep p1
Left    Join prep p2
        On  p1.EmployeeID = p2.EmployeeID
        And p1.pID = p2.pID + 1
Where   IsNull(p1.UpperLimit,0) <> -1
And     p1.ApprovalGoesTo Is Not Null
```

Comment: You are in the zone, but not exactly there. I've modified the example to include all the details. Thank you. You query returns (10,20,0,999), which should be (10,10,0,100) and (10,20,101,1000)

Comment: Ah, gotcha, so they can approve themselves up to their own limit, k... modifying now.